# Bat error set was unexpected this time

Tags: batch-file

Hello i need help with my .bat program it fails here for some

[image]

Comment: Wrong syntax. Should be `if exist "....." (set "loginpass=true") else (set "loginpass=false")` Also you can directly go to labels in the first comparison.

Comment: You should include your code in the question, not in an image though.

Comment: When testing if the variable is equal to true or false you should also have quotes around true and false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's disassemble your line

```
if else set "loginpass=false
```

Syntax is: `if <string1> <condition> <string2> <command>`

so, your `<string1>` would be `else`, your `<condition>` would be `set` - wait - that is not a valid condition, is it? So it tells you "sorry, I don't know what to do with `set` in this place"

wOxxOm gave you a better Syntax in his comment:

```
if exist "....." (set "loginpass=true") else (set "loginpass=false")
```

He also suggested to use `goto` in this place:

```
 if exist "....." (goto :loginpass) else (goto :errornum3)
```

Comment: Yeah i think im going with that